# How to load the existing page elements in a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a form in my page and I would like to also open this form in a Bootstrap modal when a link is clicked. Is there a way to use the existing mark-up in the page and load it in a modal dynamically without duplicating the mark-up?

I thought I could wrap the default BS4 modal code around my form like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>...</form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then call it with:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" class="file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Apply">
```

but then I realized the above makes my form disappeared on the page by default and only accessible via the modal. I played around with the wrapped form with `display:block` and `opacity:1` to make it appear on the page but that only makes things more complicated. Is there a better way to accomplish this and load the form with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the wrapped modal code around the form and moved it as an empty modal towards the bottom of the page and then this worked for me to collect, trim and load the empty modal's body:

```
var applyForm = $('#apply-form').html(); // this is the form ID
var trimedFormHtml = $.trim(applyForm); // removed the white space in the code 
$('.modal-body').html(trimedFormHtml); // loaded up the modal body
```